# How to modify the value of variable in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xsl file which is fetching data and storing in a variables .I have a value 1 stored in a variable . Now i want to modify the variable value i.e. if it contains 1 it should be replaced by activated . How can i do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Once you have set a variable's value, you cannot change or modify that
>   value!

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_variable.asp

Let's say you have this:

```
<xsl:variable name="var">1</xsl:variable>
```

Then, everywhere you need, you can use the following section (works in XSLT 1.0) and it will put `activated` value in your output if `$var` is equal to 1 (or the value of `$var` otherwise).

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$var=1">activated</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$var"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Or you can declare new variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="var2">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$var=1">activated</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$var"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

In this case, you will have to use  instruction to print it in the output:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$var2" />
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz . Then how can i get the output i wanted ?

Comment: Lukasz , in second line activated is stored in $var ? bcoz i am outputting $var as a html or i can directly output it .